# Java conversion to php?

Tags: java, php

Is it possible to convert this java code snippet to php?

```
public void testBalanceReturnsToZeroOnVending()
        {
            sodaVendor.insertCoin(50);
            sodaVendor.insertCoin(20);
            sodaVendor.insertCoin(5);
            // The price is right!
            assertEquals("We have entered correct money", 
                SODA_PRICE,
                sodaVendor.getCurrentBalance());
            sodaVendor.dispenseItem();
            assertEquals("After vending, the balance of soda vending machine is zero", 
                0,
                sodaVendor.getCurrentBalance());
        }
```

Comment: is that homework ? yeah that's definitely possible ... but ...

Comment: damn. soda in our vending machine costs a buck

Comment: who upvoted that question ?!?!? ......

Comment: @RageZ whoever downvoted your answer. it wasn't me though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming PHPUnit is your unit testing framework:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
// require the file containing the class that sodaVendor is an instance of

define('SODA_PRICE', 75);

class SodaVendorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $sodaVendor;

    public function setUp() {
        // set up $this->sodaVendor somehow...
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        $this->sodaVendor = null;
    }

    public function testBalanceReturnsToZeroOnVending() {
        $this->sodaVendor->insertCoin(50);
        $this->sodaVendor->insertCoin(20);
        $this->sodaVendor->insertCoin(5);
        // The price is right!
        $this->assertEquals(SODA_PRICE,
            $this->sodaVendor->getCurrentBalance(),
            "We have entered correct money");
        $this->sodaVendor->dispenseItem();
        $this->assertEquals(0,
            $this->sodaVendor->getCurrentBalance(),
            "After vending, the balance of soda vending machine is zero");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not valid. `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP. You need things like `$sodaVendor->insertCoin(50);`.

Comment: @Josh Leitzel: The answer was totally appropriate for the question and any minor errors have been corrected.

Comment: @Josh .... someone would close that question anyway ... that's not a real question !!!!

Comment: @Rage: You didn't seem to mind posting your 'response' to try to get some rep, did you?

Comment: @Asaph: I have removed my downvote because you fixed the errors and removed the condescension. But for the record, I don't believe "It's not rocket science" is something appropriate for *any* question, especially when it's being posed by a relatively new user.

Comment: Also just went ahead and upvoted since you've made a good effort to show the OP how something (generally) in Java can be implemented with PHP.

Comment: @Josh Leitzel: I appreciate the upvote. Glad I was able to convert you from an downvoter to an upvoter. Ironically (perhaps from your perspective), the final answer I ended up with for this question was what I had in mind from the start. I just worked on it incrementally in the way many SO users do. So the first few drafts were not as pretty, I suppose.

Comment: @RageZ: the method name `assertEquals()` was a big hint for me. :)

Comment: "It's not rocket science" is condescending? Subjective. I beg to differ.

Comment: @Amarghosh: I removed it in any case. If even a single person found it distasteful, it doesn't belong in my answer.

Comment: I removed my downvote as well now that the answer has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Any Java code can be converted to PHP

Comment: @Itay Moav: That's not generally true. PHP doesn't support threading for example.

Comment: @Asaph: Well, you could still pull it off effectively - just emulate co-operative multithreading.  Not that I'd recommend it.

Comment: @Kevin Montrose: @Itay Moav: Another example of a java program that would not be possible to write in PHP is an Applet.

Comment: @Applet: I believe that with the correct plugin and GTK you actually can do something like an Applet, it is just that no one ever thought of trying it...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can "translate" your Java code to PHP. Just it would have been nice you explain in the question a bit more what you are attending to do.

```
public function testBalanceReturnsToZeroOnVending()
        {
            $sodaVendor->insertCoin(50);
            $sodaVendor->insertCoin(20);
            $sodaVendor->insertCoin(5);
            // The price is right!

            assert("We have entered correct money", 
               SODA_PRICE ==
                $sodaVendor->getCurrentBalance());
            $sodaVendor->dispenseItem();
            assert("After vending, the balance of soda vending machine is zero", 
                0 == 
                $sodaVendor->getCurrentBalance());
        }
```

Comment: This isn't valid PHP. PHP variables start with $

Comment: If you think a question is "nonsense," flag it and be on your way.

Comment: @josh: sure Josh ... I will pass next time

Comment: cleaned away bad comments and the "nonsense" which is right is not nice to the user who asked the question, with my excuses.